# URL changes randomly unexpectedly

Tags: html, url, session-state

This is what my URL should look like (used to look like):

```
http://website.gov/Publication/NewPub.aspx
```

But something happened and now it looks like this:

```
http://website.gov/%28S%28osxbddfuz00gzs4525gjzd55%29%29/Publication/NewPub.aspx
```

`%28S%28osxbddfuz00gzs4525gjzd55%29%29` changes every time the page reloads.  This happens on every page on my site. This happens locally and in production.

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: Ahha...In the web config file...<sessionState cookieless="true"/>